# Is it possible to replicate the PHPFoxV3 Design Profile feature in V4?

Tags: php, html, css, phpfox

Essentially in the old PHPFox V3 each user could actively edit the CSS on their profile page, which let them give visitors a unique experience. At the same time, a user could easily check a box reading "Hide Custom CSS" and be given the sitewide stylesheet. In PHPFox V4 they removed this feature during the full rebuild. I was wondering if this fix is as easy as it looks, i.e. creating a page to accept CSS code in a textbox, convert that to a [username].css file and loading it to a user's specific page. The problem with that is, PHPFox tends to make nothing that simple, and will, in a sense, fight to force its settings. Anyone have experience?

Answer (score 0):

I use PHPFox and since moving to 4.6 I am sorry to say that at the moment it is not possible unless you are a programmer or can pay one sorry :( I like the ;look and feel of 3 too but its just not secure like 4.+